# Access Blackberry switch on/off and data usage logs

Tags: blackberry

Not sure if this is the right place to ask the question.

I have a Blackberry Curve 9300 phone. Is it possible the access logs which shows when the phone was switched on and off. Also if it is logged when the data was used over network and over WiFi.

I would like to access it without using any code if possible. However, I do not mind a quick and dirty C# application that could allow me to do so. This is a once off activity and I do not really want to invest lot of time in writing code.

Answer (score 0):

try using EventLogger API to get System events,and save it in Persistant DB as as the part of the your application and use it when required